# Reduce user's coins by 1 for each extra time taken after a specific limit - Python

Tags: python

Imagine a situation where users have 10 coins and have 40 second to do a task. I want to implement something like this: if total time taken by the user is 50, reduce the coin by 1, similary if it's 60, reduce 2 and so on...
How should I implement this in python.

PS: In short, I wanna reduce coins for each 10 seconds elapsed after 40 seconds (for example)

Comment: You calculate the elapsed time according to the duplicate, and deduct `(elapsed_time-40)//10`

Answer (score 0):

Python has a time library you can use. Something like this maybe.

```
import time

coins = 10


def user_task():
    start_time = time.time()
    # user completes task here
    end_time = time.time()
    time_taken = end_time - start_time

    return time_taken
   

total_time_taken = user_task()

if total_time_taken >= 50:
    coins = coins - 1
```

Comment: that will only take 1 coin if time >=50, it will not take 2 coins for time >=60 or 3 coins for time >=70...

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Correct, the original poster will need to modify it for additional measurements. I wasn't going to type all that out when it's self explanatory. I understood his question as having to do with the timing portion, rather than sets of if/else statements.

Comment: well you don't really need if else statements. Just substract 40 and then divide the excess by 10. eg: time = 70  ->  70-40=30 -> 30/10=3 coins substracted. That's why I mentioned that your answer was missing that calculation that gives you the result